# TOP 10 with Dynamic Ranking showing arrows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking

I'm trying to recreate a similar ranking table as this one with my data, where arrows shows, within a TOP 10, which subject rose or dropped in position: [image]

My reasoning was to create a TOP 10 filter, then a measure with RANKX and then another one but only this time using DATEADD to establish a month prior. A third column calculating the difference and a little conditional formating should do the job. Can I achieve it this way?

So far I've tried:

```
Ranking = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(ZVC_PB_01[Name]),[Debt],,DESC)
```

and

```
Ranking_mes = calculate(RANKX(ALLSELECTED(ZVC_PB_01[Name]),[Debt],,DESC), DATEADD(Calendario2[Date], -1, month))
```

Problem is the second one is not working as intended, since I assume it's only calculating the ranking within the current Top 10 (there are more subjects and some should go in and others go out). How can I work around this?

Thanks in advance!